Baby Rudin Chapter 1 Exercise 20: Disproving the additive inverse
In Baby Rudin Chapter 1 Exercise 20, we are asked to show that the additive inverse property fails if we omit property III of "cuts" i.e. that a cut $A$ has no largest element.
For those unfamiliar, a cut $A$ is any proper subset of $Q$  that is (I) nonempty; (II) for any $p \in A$, if $q \in Q$ and $q < p$, then $q \in A$; (III) for any $p \in A$, $\exists r \in A$ such that $r > p$.
Now, I am aware there is a stronger proof than this, so I am asking whether this line of reasoning meets the requirement of the additive inverse property "failing". The proof follows:
Let A and B be cuts. Let $0^*$ be the additive identity := non-positive rationals. Let $A + B = 0^*$. Ignoring the trivial answer $A = B = 0^*$, we must have $A > B$. If $B > 0^*$, then $A + B > 0^*$. So, we have $A > 0^* > B$.
Let $p \in A$ and $q \in B$. Then, we have $p + q \leq 0$. So we can define the elements $q \in B$ to be such that $p \leq -q$ for any $p \in A$. Clearly $A + B \subset 0^*$. It is left to prove that $0^* \subseteq A + B$.
As $A \neq Q$, $z \in Q$ such that if $a < z$, $a \in A$ and if $z < a$, $a \notin A$. If $z \notin A$, then $A$ doesn't have a largest element, so $A + B$ will not and it is impossible for $A + B = 0^*$ (The stronger proof finds this cut directly, namely the negative rationals). If $z \in A$, then $-z \in B$ and $A + B = 0^*$. Since we cannot generally determine whether $z \in A$, we cannot show that $A + B = 0^*$.
